# Android | How to make UI like foodpanda detail page

Tags: android, view

i am new in android development. I want to know how can i make menu view like FoodPanda. In food panda menu view if i keep scrolling the header changes according to the scrolled section. If i scroll chicken roll to siper mixed nimko my header changes as well.
I have tried connecting two list view, but it did not work.
Please click on the hyperlink to see the reference video

[FoodPanda Menu View](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nuo1BikddCholWrhhkrmPDDeEbvWAymr/view?usp=sharing)
[image]

Comment: please share some of your code, because your video can't help us to help you :)

Comment: I want a build a menu like this,Is there any way you know i can use to make this kind of view?